# DynamoDB won't let me see the data stored in my tables

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I'm using Mobilehub from AWS and I have connected DynamoDB to my app, when I upload a new file and then go to my projects, select my backend, then a list of features added to my projects are shown, press on the nosql database, it shows me my tables, their partition keys, amount of items, but I can't not see what inside my tables, I press on them but nothing happens. Does mobile hub work this way, I'm looking in the wrong place? In datastore from GCP I can see my table and all the items added to it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Resources` link on the top-right shows you all the resources linked to that project. On the resources page, the DynamoDB tables can be found. Click the respective tables and the items in the table can be viewed.